# Converting specific parts of lists to a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large list of 2 elements containing lists of species containing lists of 25 vectors, resembling a set like this:

```
l1 <- list(time=runif(100), space=runif(100))
l2 <- list(time=runif(100), space=runif(100))

list1 <- list(test1=list(species1=l1, species2=l2),test2=list(species1=l1, species2=l2))
```

I think, its essentially a list of a list of lists.of vectors.

I want to create a data.frame from all space-vectors of all 'species' in just one of the two sublists:

```
final <- as.data.frame(cbind(unlist(list1[[2]]$species1$space), unlist(list1[[2]]$species2$space)))
names(final) <- names(list1[[2]])
```

Essentially, i need a loop/apply command that navigates me through `list1[[2]]$species` and picks all vectors called space.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `data.frame(lapply(list1, function(x) sapply(x, `[`, 'space')))`

Comment: Thank you. it doesnt like the [, though: `Error: unexpected '[' in "df1 <- data.frame(lapply(list1, function(x) sapply(x, ["` Do i mess up?

Comment: I actually meant `"["` , but I was using the backquotes which didn't show up.

Comment: Cool. I does loop through both top level lists, but i can easily split the data.frame. You helped me alot.

Comment: I posted my comment as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a nested loop to extract the 'space' elements

```
data.frame(lapply(list1, function(x) 
          sapply(x, "[", 'space')))
```